# return multiple values from a function in C without struct, tuple and any thing else that above an array level

Tags: c, arrays, return-value, func

so I have this function.

```
int something(int Data1[], int Data2[], int size) {
    int data3[2],
    data[0] = return1int(sortedData1, size);
    data[1] = return1int(sortedData2, size);
    return (I dont know);
}
```

and I am trying to find a way to return those two values (data[1], data[0]) to some int in the main.
and my Q is how can I do that WITHOUT using struct at all and without changing my int in the main to an array.

thanks thanks thanks !!!

Comment: Is this definitely C++ and not C (which is a totally different language) as the answer for C is totally different

Comment: c++ has pass by reference, maybe that could help you.

Comment: "_I am trying to find a way to return those two values_" First thought: [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair). "_how can I do that WITHOUT using struct at all and without changing my int in the main to an array_" Oh.. You cannot. Unless you modified the signature to accept reference to variables, which you would use as output variables.

Comment: [If you have unusual constraints, it’s worth explaining why. Not only does this answer the obvious follow-up comment, but it also gives more information about what other solutions may not be applicable.](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Don't tag `C` if you want `C++`.

Comment: If you can't change the signature of `int something(int Data1[], int Data2[], int size) {` I doubt this can be done without some Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Weird constraints yield weird solutions.

Comment: C doesnt have `std::pair` but you can write a toy `pair` easily, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use std::pair (because it's C++) or a struct (nothing wrong with that in my opinion though), you could still go for out parameters.

```
void something(int Data1[], int Data2[], int size, int& out1, int& out2) {
    int data3[2],
    out1 = return1int(sortedData1, size);
    out2 = return1int(sortedData2, size);
}
```

Comment: The tag has been changed from `c++` to `c`

Answer (score 0):

In C you can pass a pointer to a variable to update it's value so your function could look like this

```
void something(int Data1[], int Data2[], int size,int *ret1, int *ret2) {

    *ret1 = return1int(sortedData1, size);
    *ret2 = return1int(sortedData2, size);
    return;
}
```

and you'd call it something like this

```
something(array1,array2,size,&value1,&value2);
```

and `value1` and `value2` would contain the values returned by the function. And that leaves the actual return value from the function to be used to indicate a success or error condition.